# Can RemoteSigned run scripts created on same domain?

Tags: powershell

I'm creating and testing some powershell scripts to do some basic file copying.  I've set my executionpolicy to RemoteSigned.  According to the help, this should allow me to run scripts that were not downloaded from the internet.  However, my observations seem to indicate that this will run only scripts created on the local machine.

For instance, if I create a script on my development machine and try to copy to my server (on my same domain), the script will not run.  However, if I open up the Powershell ISE on the server and open my script, copy the code and paste it into a new file window and save it to the server, the script then runs.  Further, if I want to create a self-signed certificate, it will not run on other computers (per the help).

So, this all seems a bit cumbersome that I have to develop my scripts on the machine they are to be run or go through the copy/paste routine mentioned above to get them to run on my server.  I just want to know that I've understood all of this correctly and there is no other way to create a script within the same domain and run it under the remotesigned execution policy without paying the fee for a certificate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this [post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/10/29/how-to-run-powershell-scripts-from-a-shared-directory.aspx) here provide the method for executing script from shared folder. hope this could help you :-)